# Print everything in my context

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I am trying to do something funny with nodejs that requires me to run a single statement in javascipt that `shows all the objects that are present in the current context`.

These objects might be just created by me or by the nodejs environment.

Is this facilitated in javascript ?

One use can be for debugging purposes.

Comment: Short answer: it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from js level. You can get all frame and closure scope variables from debugger (and it's very easy to automate - `require('_debugger')`. If this is something you ready to try I can explain details of [V8 debugger protocol](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol) and built in node.js client for it.

Update:

Basic usage of debugger client from node core:

```
var DebuggerClient = require('_debugger').Client;
var dc = new DebuggerClient();
dc.connect(5858);  // you need to start your script with "node --debug-brk=5858 script-to-debug.js"

// listen breakpoint:
dc.on('break', function(res) {
   // sctipt id, line, location here
   dc.reqBacktrace(function(err, res) {
      // res.frames array
   });

   dc.reqScopes(function(scopes) {
      // SCOPES! TADAM!
   });

});
```

Try first using "debugger" keyword, inspect results, then continue with setting/changing breakpoints from your script.

See how it's [used in node](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_debugger.js), in [node-vim-debugger](https://github.com/sidorares/node-vim-debugger) and if something missing refer to [V8 debugger protocol documentation](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol)

Note that you have access to [similar API](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/debug-debugger.js) from the script being debugged itself, see how [it is used to set breakpoint at the beginning of the script](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L445)

```
// script is a reference to Script object, see "vm" module
global.v8debug.Debug.setBreakPoint(script, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know about build in nodejs client.

Comment: It's not documented/internal (yet?). I'll update to answer.